# Electron - dialog.showOpenDialogSync() is not allowing both files and folders

Tags: javascript, electron

I'm trying to open both files and folders into an electron desktop app with the standard `dialog.showOpenDialogSync()`
although I'm setting the properties of the `dialog.showDialogSync()` function as `["openDirectory","openFile", "multiSelections"]` , I am not able to select both folders and files. it's either folders or files. which electron decides based on which is first on the array.

**The code where I'm able to select folders**

```
let files = dialog.showOpenDialogSync({

   properties: ["openDirectory","openFile", "multiSelections"]

  }
);
```

**The code where I'm able to select files**

```
let files = dialog.showOpenDialogSync({

   properties: ["openFile","openDirectory", "multiSelections"]

  }
);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [API docs](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/dialog#dialogshowopendialogsyncbrowserwindow-options), this is behaviour is to be expected, as it's not possible to select both a file and a directory on Windows and Linux.

> Note: On Windows and Linux an open dialog can not be both a file selector and a directory selector, so if you set properties to `['openFile', 'openDirectory']` on these platforms, a directory selector will be shown.